# Community self registration page jquery

Tags: community, jquery, id, remote-action

I have the following code in the CommunitiesSelfReg page

```
<apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="First Name: " for="firstName"/>
                      <apex:outputLabel id="firstNameDisplay" value="{!firstName}"  />
                      <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Last Name: " for="lastName"/>
                      <apex:outputLabel id="lastNameDisplay" value="{!lastName}" />
                      <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Email: " for="email"/>
                      <apex:outputLabel id="emailDisplay" value="{!email}" />

<apex:inputHidden id="firstName" value="{!firstName}"   />
                <apex:inputHidden id="lastName" value="{!lastName}"  />
                <apex:inputHidden id="email" value="{!email}" />
               <apex:inputHidden id="contactId" value="{!contactId}"    />


 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.CommunitiesSelfRegController.getContactInfo}',
            contactId, 
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    if (result != null){
                        jQuery("[id$=firstName]").attr("value", result.FirstName );  
                        jQuery("[id$=lastName]").attr("value", result.LastName  );  
                        jQuery("[id$=email]").attr("value", result.Email  );  
                        jQuery("[id$=communityNickname]").attr("value", result.Email  ); 

var sContactId = jQuery("[id$=contactId]").attr("value"); 
    var sPubId= jQuery("[id$=pubId]").attr("value");
    if (sContactId !=''){
        getRemoteContact(sContactId);
else {
        // cannot find the reference to contact. display error message, disable submit button
        ***jQuery("#responseErrors").html("Sorry, Invalid Contact ID"+sPubId);***
```

In the controller

```
public string firstName{
        get {
            if (pfirstName == null){
                pfirstName = '';
            } 
            return pfirstName;
        }
        set { 
            pfirstName = value;
        }   
    }

    private string plastName = null;
    public string lastName{
        get {
            if (plastName == null){
                plastName = '';
            } 
            return plastName;
        }
        set { 
            plastName = value;
        }   
    }
    private string pEmail = null;
    public string Email{
        get {
            if (pEmail == null){
                pEmail = '';
            } 
            return pEmail;
        }
        set { 
            pEmail = value;
        }   

    @RemoteAction
    global static Contact getContactInfo(String contactId) {
        Contact result = [SELECT Id, Name, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, MailingCity, MailingStreet, MailingState, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode 
                   FROM Contact WHERE id = :contactId];
        return result;
    }
```

The controller class method which redirects to the CommunitiesSelfReg page is this

```
Public Pagereference RegisterA(){
    PageReference page = new pagereference('/apex/CommunitiesSelfReg?'+'&ContactId='+ContactId+'&Id='+pId+'%26sfdc.tabName%3C01ri00000004OyY%26submenu%3DPlan%26tile%3DPub%2BDetails');

    return page;
}
```

This is showing to an error

> Sorry, Invalid Contact ID

.It is not printing the value of sPubId. Can someone tell me  where am I making the mistake? Its really urgent

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
var sContactId = jQuery("[id$=contactId]").attr("value");
```

into this

```
var sContactId = jQuery("[id$=contactId]").val();
```

Comment: Its still not working @tusharsharma

Comment: @Rimii check if you are getting ID in inputhidden.